# Does returning a standard container incur a copy of the contents of the container?

Tags: c++, optimization, stl, containers, standard-library

If I have a function that returns an STL container am I incurring a copy of the entire contents of the standard container?

e.g. Is this:

```
void Foo( std::vector< std::string >* string_list );
```

better than this:

```
std::vector< std::string > Foo();
```

Does it matter what's in the container? For instance would returning a container like this:

```
struct buzz {
    int a;
    char b;
    float c;
}

std::map< int, buzz > Foo();
```

be a more costly operation than this:

```
std::map< int, int > Foo();
```

Thanks,
PaulH

---

**Edit:**
This is with C++03. A C++0x solution is, unfortunately, not acceptable.

**Edit2:**
I am using the Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 compiler.

Comment: More importantly, does it matter? No. Write the code to be *clean* and *straightforward*, then when you're done you can use a profiler to see what the slow parts are. If returning from a function is taking up a large amount of time, only then is it worth it to obfuscate your code for performance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C++03 will probably do (named) return value optimization (google RVO and NRVO).

If that optimization is not applicable, C++0x will do [move semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/).

Answer (score 3):

I wasn't 100% sure, but NO (thanks to the commentators) :

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

#define LOCAL_FUN

struct A {
    A() { std::cout << "default ctor" << std::endl; }
    A(const A &a) { std::cout << "copy ctor" << std::endl; }
};

#ifdef LOCAL_FUN
std::vector<A> *pVec = NULL;
#endif

std::vector<A> func()
{
    std::vector<A> vec;
#ifdef LOCAL_FUN
    pVec = &vec;
#endif
    vec.push_back(A());
    std::cout << "returning" << std::endl;
    return vec;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::vector<A> ret = func();
#ifdef LOCAL_FUN
    if (pVec) {
        std::cout << pVec->size();
    }
#endif
}
```

output (with LOCAL_FUN):

```
default ctor
copy ctor
returning
1
```

Edit: Some more playing with the code led me to some fun with the local variables (LOCAL_FUN). So a really bad compiler that does not optimize copying, can actually break this code...

Comment: The copy is made in `push_back`, **not** during returning. In fact, your code shows that *no* copy is made during returning.

Comment: Oh, damn I intended to write "no" - need some sleep.

Comment: Note that although this is the most likely result, output showing the "copy ctor" twice (or even three times) is also correct and would not mean a broken compiler, just a missed optimization.

Comment: three times? Where is the third? I see the first one in `push_back(A())`, possible second in `std::vector<A> ret = func();`. Also, is it possible to avoid the first one?

Comment: @ak you can avoid the first one with `vec.emplace_back();` instead of `vec.push_back(A());` (requires C++0x support)

Comment: @ak: `std::vector<A> ret = func();` can involve copying the vector twice (and hence of an instance of `A`) - one from the automatic variable `vec` to the temporary which is the return value of the function call `func()`, and another to initialize `ret` using that temporary. It's no coincidence that those are precisely the two situations where the standard allows copy constructor elision.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it will involve a copy of the container, but don't use `void Foo( std::vector< std::string >* string_list );`. Use `void foo( vector<string>& string_list);` instead.

Or just switch to C++0x and use a compiler that has already move optimizations implemented in the library.

Comment: It may not incur a copy. In fact, it won’t in most cases. It really depends on the content of the function.

Comment: Why do you prefer the reference semantics? I've always liked the pass-by-pointer method for values I'm intending to modify within the function so that the user has to put that little `&` in when calling the function. Like signifying they understand my function will change the value.

Comment: Pointers are semantically weaker which will allow the compiler to ignore clear code errors. Another huge issue is propagating const through pointers (huge pain).

Comment: @Paul: Then your function should be better named. There's no confusion that `swap(x, y)` is going to modify `x` and `y`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

First compiler is required to elide copy construction, if can't, then move, if can't then copy. So if you have a really bad compiler, you risk incurring an overhead of an extra copy. See [this discussion](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/) for details.

Comment: There is no _requirement_ that copies be elided; there is merely an allowance that a compile _may_ elide a copy under some circumstances.

Comment: Elision isn't required.  It's not even required that the implementation "try" elision first.

Comment: @James McNellis, @Fred Nurk -- you might have parsed my reply incorrectly. I didn't mean to say that compiler required to elide, I just put the sequence compiler going through before deciding to copy.

Comment: Here is a correct wording, that shouldn't cause confusion: When you pass an rvalue by value, or return anything by value from a function, the compiler first gets the option to elide the copy. If the copy isn’t elided, but the type in question has a move constructor, the compiler is required to use the move constructor. Lastly, if there’s no move constructor, the compiler falls back to using the copy constructor.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the copy constructor of the container. C++ has pass by value semantics. So when you return a vector for function Foo() it will be returned using value semantics i.e. a copy constructor will be invoked to copy the value of the vector.  In this case the copy constructor of std::vector creates a new container and copies the values. In case of passing a pointer to the container you would have to allocate the memory if you have not allocated it already so the pointer points to an actual container and not a null value. From a programming practice perspective this is not a good thing to do because you leave the semantics open to interpretation. Better idea would be to pass a reference to the container and let the function fill the container with the desired elements.

Comment: This isn’t true. See Fred’s answer for why your answer is wrong.